# Excel Macro Error Code 424 works when slowly clicking through

Tags: vba, excel

```
'start a new subroutine called SearchBot

Sub SearchBot()

'dimension (declare or set aside memory for) our variables
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 'special object variable representing the IE browser
Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 'special object variable for an <a> (link) element
Dim y As Integer 'integer variable we'll use as a counter
Dim result As String 'string variable that will hold our result link



 Dim x As Integer
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  ' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
  NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
  ' Select cell a1.
  Range("A1").Select
  ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
  For x = 1 To NumRows
     ' Insert your code here.

     'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
objIE.Visible = True

'navigate IE to this web page (a pretty neat search engine really)
objIE.navigate "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/vatResponse.html"

'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

'in the search box put cell "A2" value, the word "in" and cell "C1" value
objIE.document.getElementById("countryCombobox").Value = "GB"
objIE.document.getElementById("number").Value = ActiveCell.Value

'click the 'go' button
objIE.document.getElementById("submit").Click

'wait again for the browser
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop



     Dim vatResponse As String

     vatResponse = objIE.document.getElementById("vatResponseFormTable").getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).Children(0).textContent

     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = vatResponse

     ' Selects cell down 1 row from active cell.

  'Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True       

'close the browser
objIE.Quit

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    'End

Next

'exit our SearchBot subroutine
End Sub
```

So basically on this code line:

```
vatResponse = objIE.document.getElementById("vatResponseFormTable").getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).Children(0).textContent
```

I am getting an error message saying that I have an error code 424

Comment: Please can you provide a better explanation of your issue

Comment: Please add more infomation and code to your question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have added more detail, @UGP

Comment: @Jordan I have added more detail

Comment: Error 424 means "Object Required" so you should split this line and check for `Is Nothing` - `Set tbl=objIE.document.getElementById("vatResponseFormTable"): If Not tbl Is Nothing Then <proceed with program>`

Comment: @SBF can't get this to work still, it's weird because when I run it slowly by clicking f8 it works all the way through

Comment: The code runs okay for me if I provide a dummy vat#. I get text "No, invalid VAT number (please refer to FAQ, questions 7, 11, 12, 13 and 20 for more information)."  Can you provide a valid vat# to try the code?

Comment: @sktneer 577300832 this is a valid vat number

Comment: Okay. I have just added a solution and see if this approach works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the pages gets loaded internally through some scripts so the html element you are trying to get actually isn't found on the document as the code runs very fast. So somehow you have to wait until page loads completely.

Please try this approach and see if the code runs without producing an error.

```
Sub SearchBot()

'dimension (declare or set aside memory for) our variables
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 'special object variable representing the IE browser
Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 'special object variable for an <a> (link) element
Dim vatFormTable As IHTMLElement
Dim tr As IHTMLElement
Dim y As Integer 'integer variable we'll use as a counter
Dim result As String 'string variable that will hold our result link

Dim x As Integer
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 ' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
 NumRows = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 ' Select cell a1.
 Range("A1").Select
 ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
 For x = 1 To NumRows
    ' Insert your code here.

    'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
objIE.Visible = True

'navigate IE to this web page (a pretty neat search engine really)
objIE.navigate "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/vatResponse.html"

'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

'in the search box put cell "A2" value, the word "in" and cell "C1" value
objIE.document.getElementById("countryCombobox").Value = "GB"
objIE.document.getElementById("number").Value = ActiveCell.Value

'click the 'go' button
objIE.document.getElementById("submit").Click

'wait again for the browser
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop


    On Error Resume Next
    Dim vatResponse As String
    Do While vatFormTable Is Nothing
       Set vatFormTable = objIE.document.getElementById("vatResponseFormTable")
    Loop

    Do While tr Is Nothing
       Set tr = vatFormTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")(0)
    Loop

    vatResponse = tr.Children(0).innerText
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = vatResponse

    ' Selects cell down 1 row from active cell.

 'Next
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'close the browser
objIE.Quit

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   'End

Next

'exit our SearchBot subroutine
End Sub
```